# Expo and Native Base unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: react-native, native-base

Fresh install expo init firstapp then next npm install native-base. I encounter error like this below. I tried deleting node_modules and tried also deleting expo cli I have no success.

Anyone encounter this?

```
PS E:\Projects\ReactNative\firstapp> npm install native-base
>>
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: react@16.13.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.13.1" from react-dom@16.13.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@">=16.5.1" from react-native-web@0.13.18
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-native-web
npm ERR!       react-native-web@"~0.13.12" from the root project
npm ERR!     react-dom@"16.13.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from react-native-safe-area-context@3.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context
npm ERR!     react-native-safe-area-context@"3.2.0" from expo@41.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/expo
npm ERR!       expo@"~41.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   5 more (react-native-web, use-subscription, the root project, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-native-windows@0.64.8
npm ERR! node_modules/native-base/node_modules/react-native-windows
npm ERR!   peer react-native-windows@">=0.62" from @react-native-community/datetimepicker@3.5.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/native-base/node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/datetimepicker@"^3.0.2" from native-base@2.15.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/native-base
npm ERR!       native-base@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-23T08_04_02_291Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Which version of react you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like maybe the solution to your problem might be to use a compatible version of native base with your react native version see table in [native base documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-base) on the **Compatibility Versions** section.